# I can't change the color of text on the Xamarin Forms Shell

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

If I use dark mode on my smartphone black color stays white only becomes more saturated. The black and white images are displayed in negative. I tried changing the code in AppShell.xaml, but nothing worked.

AppShell.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App.Views"
       Title="App"
       x:Class="App.AppShell">

    <!--
        The overall app visual hierarchy is defined here, along with navigation.
    
        https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/
    -->

    <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
                <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="#0f4057" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
            <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Shell.Resources>

    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Title="Text" Icon="icon_feed.pn" Route="Page1" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Text" Icon="icon_feed.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Text" Icon="icon_feed.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page3}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Text" Icon="icon_feed.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page4}" />
    </TabBar>

    <!--
        If you would like to navigate to this content you can do so by calling
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//LoginPage");
    -->
    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Route="LoginPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
    </TabBar>

</Shell>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at theme support which allows you to define a dark and light theme for your app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application.Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme.Dark;` to get the theme of the current user and change it by binding AppThemeBinding.